# Padding top creates extra gap between element of absolute child

Tags: html, css, padding

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Online HTML Editor</title>
<head>
    <style>
        .section{
            position:relative;
            min-height: 20vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 25px 15px 15px;
            background: red;
        }
        .section:nth-child(even){
            background: transparent;
        }
        .floater{
            position: absolute;
            background: #31ff0057;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">First Section. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias debitis, natus cum in ipsum, officia tempore repudiandae repellat accusantium rerum iusto voluptatem nostrum hic nihil alias soluta, iure quo magnam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
<div class="section">
    <div>Second Section</div>
    <div class="floater">Floater</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Third Section</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the second section creates extra gap between first two sections because of the child element `<div class="floater">Floater</div>`,I don't know why it's vreating a gap and also don't know how to get rid of the gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to add the `top` property to your `.floater` element. I added `top:0;` to it and seems fine. Hope that helps.

```css
.section{
  position:relative;
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px 15px 15px;
  background: red;
}
.section:nth-child(even){
  background: transparent;
}
.floater{
  position: absolute;
  background: #31ff0057;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">First Section. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias debitis, natus cum in ipsum, officia tempore repudiandae repellat accusantium rerum iusto voluptatem nostrum hic nihil alias soluta, iure quo magnam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
<div class="section">
    <div>Second Section</div>
    <div class="floater">Floater</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Third Section</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but why do I need to add `top: 0;` if I already have height as 100% ?? And why 
 did it create a gap ??

Comment: Yes because it is absolute to the `.section` which has padding top on it, so it going to be placed 25px from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding of `.section` or change it to e.g. `padding: 25px 15px;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Online HTML Editor</title>
<head>
    <style>
        .section{
            position:relative;
            min-height: 20vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 25px 15px 25px;
            background: red;
        }
        .section:nth-child(even){
            background: transparent;
        }
        .floater{
            position: absolute;
            background: #31ff0057;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">First Section. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias debitis, natus cum in ipsum, officia tempore repudiandae repellat accusantium rerum iusto voluptatem nostrum hic nihil alias soluta, iure quo magnam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
<div class="section">
    <div>Second Section</div>
    <div class="floater">Floater</div>
</div>
<div class="section">Third Section</div>
</body>
</html>
```